# Salesforce Outlook Add-In Blank "From Address"

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

We're just starting to roll out the Salesforce Outlook Add-In at my org.  Some of our users use a different email address in Outlook than they do in Salesforce.  I've already checked that their alternative email is listed in the "My Acceptable Email Addresses" section in Settings.

They can use the add-in just fine and can send emails that get linked to the correct Salesforce records.

The problem is that when an email is linked to a Salesforce record, the "From Address" and "From Name" are left blank.  It tracks who created the email record but doesn't add the User information.

Also, if a user has the same email in Salesforce and Outlook, the "From Address" and "From Name" populate correctly.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image: blank fields]

Comment: Just to clarify - the outlook users whose emails match the Salesforce user email, then the from address gets populated as expected?  Can you update your post to clarify this?

Comment: Thanks @BrianMiller, I updated the post.  If a user's email in Salesforce matches Outlook, the "From Address" and "From Name" populate correctly.